# MVC Dropdown list from different entity

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a view, that is of Inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<P>`.

Type P has a property of Type `C`, ie, `P` could be:

```
class P
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public C OtherData { get; set; }
}
```

The View in question is for creating a new `P`, and as such I want to create a DropDown list of all the available `C`'s.

So the dropdown could be:

- C1
- C2
- C3
- C4

I've tried creating the `List<SelectListItem>` object for the `C`'s in my controller and then pass them to the view using `ViewData` but this does not work, as when I try to submit I get the exception:

`System.InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key C.`

So my question is, how do I create a list of `C` objects to display in my View that inherits from type `P`. The list of objects is pulled from a database and as such I cannot just simply hardcode the options into the view.

Do I need to create another Model type that marries the 2 types together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do this is as follows:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ListOfCs { get; set; }
}
```

My **View** has the following:

```
<%:Html.EditorFor(model => model, new { ListOfCs = Model.ListOfCs })%>
```

I use the default Object.ascx outlined in [Brad Wilson's excellent series of blog posts on ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html)

Then I add a dropdown template for that dropdown in the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder and call it something like CClassDropDown:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" %>

<%: Html.DropDownList(null, new List<SelectListItem>(ViewData["ListOfCs"] as List<SelectListItem>), "Select C...")%>
```

And then I add a partial metadata class for the P object:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PMetaData))]
public partial class P
{
    public class PMetaData
    {
        [UIHint("CClassDropDown")] 
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public object C { get; set; }

    }
}
```

to the metadata for that class property so it knows to use the template I specified.

Comment: Thanks morgan, Where do I add this metadata class? Never seen that before!

Comment: @AndyC - you would create a partial class for the containing object (P). You can find a great explanation of how to use it in the MVC Music Store tutorial: http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/. Look for "Using MetaData Partial Classes with Entity Framework".  And incidentally, between that tutorial and Brad Wilson's templating series, I learned everything I need to know about MVC and EF4 (mostly!)

Comment: @AndyC as for where specifically to *put* the partial classes, I put them in the Model folder and I call them out with a .metadata.cs filename, so in this case: P.metadata.cs. Note that they are partial classes to the default EF4 generated classes - I don't usually do metadata partial classes on the viewmodel, although I did for your example.

Comment: @Morganpdx I assume this solution is still valid if I'm using Linq to Sql instead of EF? :)

Comment: @Andy - yes, it should work the same.  The key point is the UIHint on the partial metadata class; that can be added to any class, not just an EF-generated one.  You'll need to have the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations in your partial class for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've only done this with Linq2Sql so YMMW.

In Linq2Sql the entity has both an foreign entity, and a foreign entity key.

So, it would have both C and C_id.

```
class P
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public C OtherData { get; set; }
public int OtherData_id { get; set; }
}
```

In that case its just a case of doing

```
MyViewData {
  SelectList CList = new SelectList( ctx.getCs(), "C_id", "C_name")
}
```

and in the page  doing

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("OtherData_id", Model.CList,"-") %>
```

In this way

```
TryModelUpdate(...)
```

will correctly set the OtherData_id, which in turn will cause OtherData to be resolved when accessed.